Testing if a SQL script will run
I am looking for a way to test if a SQL script will execute on a database without actually executing the script or having permission to execute the script.  The reason for this is that my team writes code for a SQL database and we maintain that code in a DevOps repository.  When we deploy changes to the database we create a SQL script and then provide that script to a DBA to run with db_owner permissions.  Occasionally, we run into a situation where there is an error in the script and the script fails to execute when run by the DBA.
When the script fails, the DBA has to get back in touch with the developer so that the developer can diagnose the reason for the failure and then update the script so that it will execute.  I am hoping to find a way to test that the script will execute successfully so that the developer can test it before providing the script to the DBA.  I have tried running inside of a transaction that is rolled back, but if the script needs elevated permissions to run it will throw and error that permission is denied.
Update:  I am using T-SQL and SSMS.  The same scripts cannot be run in lower environments.  When dropping a constraint from a table, the constraint name will be different in TEST and PROD.  We also make direct data manuipulations and the same data does not exist in both TEST and PROD.

What language are you using? I know phpmyadmin has a build in feature to test SQL Scripts

You can try SET PARSEONLY ON  and at least it will be somewhat validated

There is a not so great way, but it probably works.
If your product database is not too big and heavy, and your programmer is allowed to see the real data of the product due to security, always share the latest full backup of the database with the programmers when you run the last successful update on the product.
They can restore that database on their test server and try queries on it until all errors in the queries are resolved. Of course, if the execution of the queries written by the programmer is time-consuming, this method may not be suitable.
On the other hand, the advantage of this method is that it is similar to a sandbox and if the programmer makes an important mistake, your real data will not be destroyed.
In addition, by right-clicking on the database and selecting the "Tasks=> Generate Scripts" menu, you can easily generate the necessary queries for the latest database changes automatically.

More details for clarification:
The respected questioner (Mr. or Mrs. Dave) said that there is a need for a way to detect errors without actually executing the script.
In my opinion, it is probably not possible, because everything may be correct in the query, but during the actual execution, it will have problems with some real data. For example, the script for creating a "Unique Constraint" may be correct, but when it is applied to a table that has at least one duplicate data, an error will occur and prevent the constraint from being activated. Therefore, if the Microsoft company considers a tool in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to simulate the execution, it will still require real data unless we only want to check the syntax of the query commands. So I proposed a method that would provide something like a sandbox to test run queries before they hit the main database. If the only problem is the names of the constraints, the constraint can be removed and then recreated by specifying the same name in both the main and test databases, but I think this is only an example of the problem. Therefore, when the database is updated with a script written by the programmer, It is better to share a copy of the actual database with the developer so that the developer can run tests on it to build the next update script in the coming days. In fact, instead of the DBA wasting time and testing probably an incorrect next query, the programmer should do this and provide the next error-free update query.
Of course, this method does not completely eliminate the possibility of script errors, but it will be much less. However, the longer the interval between creating the next scripts, the greater the possibility of the difference between the test database and the original, and the possibility of errors in the script.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
